# count all raw values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

All i am doing is saving user ratings and reviews to table and then calling it from database. Now what I want to do is add all the ratings (like: 5+4+3= 12) and then divide them by count of the ratings (12/3 = 4) and get average rating or aggregate rating.

I am able to display the reviews but how can I add all values from rating column and get average value.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($mesult) > 0) {
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($mesult);
  echo '<p class="">'.$count.' Reviews</p>';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mesult)) {
    $name =$row["name"];
    $text =$row["text"];
    $heading =$row["heading"];
    $rating =$row["rating"];
    echo '<div class="review"  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">  <meta itemprop="itemReviewed" content ="'.$title.'"/> <p class="heading"><strong>'.$heading.'</strong></p><div class="ratings" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"> <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1"/><span itemprop="ratingValue">'.$rating.'</span>/<span itemprop="bestRating">5</span></div><p class="reviewtext" itemprop="description">'.$text.'</p><div class="reviewby"  itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">'.$name.'</span></div></div>';
}
```

Also what I am querying is

```
$loutput ="SELECT * FROM rating
WHERE product=$ID";
$mesult = mysqli_query($conns,$loutput);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use MySQL's AVG() to calculate the average rating:

```
SELECT AVG(rating) AS avgRating FROM myTable;
```

This is how you round the result to X decimals:

```
 SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating), X) AS avgRating FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$loutput ="SELECT AVG(Column_name) as avg FROM rating WHERE product='".$ID."'";

$mresult=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($loutput));

echo $mresult['avg'];
```

Comment: `$loutput ="SELECT AVG(rating) FROM rating WHERE product=$ID";
$mesult = mysqli_query($conns,$loutput);`
`echo $mesult;` Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregate function 
to get the [average](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) use the avg()

SELECT avg(rating) from rating;